# How to get a single evaluation of RandomReal in a Block

Tags: evaluation, random, trigonometry, signal-processing

I want to generate (and eventually sample) a sine wave with a random frequency in the range [½, 1] (i.e. capture somewhere between half and one period of the waveform over the domain [0,1]).

The two extremes for this are

```
Plot[Sin[ \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

My initial effort for this was to replace the 2 with a call to RandomReal[{1, 2}], but this results in a different random value being used for every x.

Putting the call to RandomReal in a block has the same behavior:

```
Plot[Block[{m = RandomReal[{1, 2}]}, Sin[m \[Pi] x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Plot with RandomReal]

How can I force Mathematica to only evaluate RandomReal once so I get a single clean sine wave out?

Comment: `Show@Table[
  With[{c = RandomReal[{1, 2}]}, Plot[Sin[c \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}]], 10] ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give what I think you expect, it uses a different value for every evaluation:

```
With[{c = RandomReal[{1, 2}]},
  Plot[Sin[c \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}]
]
```

you could just as well use `Block` or `Module` for this case, but `With` is probably a bit clearer...